# Аналог TabHost на iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовывается такое в XCode?

На картинке TabHost из приложения для Android.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, подобное реализовано в iOS версии инстаграма (переключение между первой и второй вкладками профиля)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это UISegmentedControl
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html

Но если Вам нужна кастомизация, то можете воспользоваться различными библиотеками. Например,

1) github.com/dzenbot/DZNSegmentedControl

2) github.com/rs/SDSegmentedControl

3) github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

4) github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

5) github.com/pepibumur/PPiFlatSegmentedControl

6) github.com/alikaragoz/AKSegmentedControl

Либо найти подходящее тут:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=Segment

Comment: Спасибо!
4 вариант - оно!

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то нужно сделат View с buttons а если количество кнопок не влазит например на 4s то тогда scroll view.

```
LAChooseTransaction *butPayAtCounter = [[LAChooseTransaction alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];
    [butPayAtCounter setTitle: @"PAY AT\nCOUNTER" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [butPayAtCounter setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"payby_counter"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [butPayAtCounter setTag:0];
    [butPayAtCounter addTarget:self action:@selector(selectMethodNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [butPayAtCounter setTitleColor:RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.chooseView addSubview:butPayAtCounter];

    LAChooseTransaction *butPayAtLoyallty = [[LAChooseTransaction alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 80)];
    [butPayAtLoyallty setTitle: @"PAY AT\nLOYALTY APP" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [butPayAtLoyallty setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"payby_app"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [butPayAtLoyallty addTarget:self action:@selector(selectMethodNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [butPayAtLoyallty setTag:1];
    [self.chooseView addSubview:butPayAtLoyallty];
```

Comment: Количество кнопок должно влазить на любой экран. Что это за юзабилити с горизонтальными скролами :)))